# Why isn't router.currentRoute.path reactive?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have an app which is contained in this `div`:

```
<div id="app" v-bind:style='{backgroundColor: backgroundColor}'>
  ... the app ...
</div>
```

The routing is done following the [example in the documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html) (this is a webpack project):

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import ComponentOne from './component1.vue'
import ComponentTwo from './component2.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [{
        path: '/foo',
        component: ComponentOne
    },
    {
        path: '/bar',
        component: ComponentTwo
    }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

const app = new Vue({
    router,
    data: {
        day: "Monday"
    },
    computed: {
        backgroundColor: function () {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(router.currentRoute))
            if (router.currentRoute.path == "/foo") {
                return "green"
            } else {
                return "blue"
            }
        }
    }
}).$mount('#app')
```

I wanted the background to be dependent on the current route ([`router.currentRoute.path`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-instance.html#properties)).

But, the solution above does not work, because `router.currentRoute.path` is not detected by the Vue instance as having changed (is not reactive).

**What is the correct way to access the dynamic router data from within the Vue instance?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `router` object created via `new VueRouter` is not reactive because Vue has no way to know to watch and update any object outside of its scope.

Passing `router` in the `Vue` config object is what allows the current route to be watched, but you need to reference it via [`this.$route`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/component-injections.html):

```
if (this.$route.path == "/foo") {
  ...
}
```

---

You can also access the entire `router` object via `this.$router`, but its data is not reactive.

---

And if you are using Vue 2 with composition api `setup()` approach you can do this:

```js
    import { computed } from '@vue/composition-api'
    export default {
      setup (props, context) {
        const params = computed ( () => context.root.$route.params)
        const path = computed( () => context.root.$route.path)
```

Comment: I just tested (replaced `router`by `this.$router` in both the `console.log()` and the `if` condition) and the behaviour is the same: `router.currentRoute.path` is not updated after the initial setting upon route change. I will be looking into the docs to understand the `$router` notation.

Comment: Thank you. I was just typing in a comment about `this.$route` working fine (and updated your answer with the link to the docs)

Comment: Cool yeah, I didn't realize the `this.$router` object wasn't watched at all. Good to know!

Comment: I wonder, though, why `this.$route.path` is fine when `this.$router.currentRoute` is not. I would have thought that `$route` is derived from `$router`.

Comment: I don't know the internal logic, but I'm assuming that code in the VueRouter plugin specifically makes the current `$route` reactive but doesn't make the whole `$router` object reactive

Comment: I can sort of understand why it's not reactive but when you're within a Getter in Vuex i'm not aware of a way to tap into the Vue context object (aka, "this" in the above example). Does anyone know if there's a way?

Answer (score 2):

I found on Vue's [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/transitions.html#per-route-transition) page that tracks the router using watch for transition animations. Not sure if this is a best practice but you can use to.path or from.path to grab the path instead.

```
// then, in the parent component,
// watch the `$route` to determine the transition to use
watch: {
  '$route': (to, from) => {
    const toDepth = to.path.split('/').length
    const fromDepth = from.path.split('/').length
    this.transitionName = toDepth < fromDepth ? 'slide-right' : 'slide-left'
  }
}
```